# Listview no longer registers itemClickEvent with spinner in it

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a list view that displays items.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvOrderItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight=".35"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

I Have a cart_item xml file that holds the template of each item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItemImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">
...

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnQty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/accountsettings_dropdown"
                android:padding="15dp" />

...

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the code of my custom adapter.

I simply register the dropdown in the item like so:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ...

    Spinner spnQty = view.findViewById(R.id.spnQty);

    ...

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> qtyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nums);
    qtyAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnQty.setAdapter(qtyAdapter);
```

If I simply comment out `spnQty.setAdapter(qtyAdapter);` the click events on the listview now work.

Other wise the clickEvents don't register at all.

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Spinner` is a element with clickable property which will take the control of your click events and for that reason your `ListView` won't receive the chance to handle the click events.

Try adding `android:descendantFocussability=blocksDescendants` this to the top most layout of your `ListView` element xml or your `ListView`